# Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am getting this error while connecting to oracle 12c from SQL Developer,

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

My **tnsnames.ora** file contents is:

> ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
>     (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = CLRExtProc)
>         (PRESENTATION = RO)
>       )   )
>
> ORCL1 =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.1.10)(PORT = 1521))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.abc.com)
>       )   )
>
> ORCL =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = INT.abc.com)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.abc.com)
>       )   )

My **listener.ora** file contents is:

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =
>     (SID_LIST =
>       (SID_DESC =
>         (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
>         (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
>         (PROGRAM = extproc)
>         (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
>       )
>     )
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = INT.abc.com)(PORT = 1521))
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>       )   )

I am using **Service Name** as `'orcl1'` and **Host Name** as `'10.10.1.10'` in sql developer "Add Connection" window and getting the above error.

I am able to connect to sqlplus using cmd with proper username and password.
 Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to connect to SQL Developer, once i changed my **Service Name** to **"orcl.abc.com"**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are connecting through sqlplus using orcl.  check your hostname. In tnsnames.ora you are using int. abc.cm and in listener you are using ipaddress. Try to keep both same. Change hostname in tnsnames.ora to ipaddress.